# Synchronize VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts between Windows and Unix

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

VS Code has a "Settings Sync" feature to synchronize settings between different installations. However, it does not sync Keyboard Shortcuts across platforms. I want the same Keyboard Shortcuts for both Unix and Windows, and I want it to automatically update all installations when I make a change anywhere.  I've manually copied keybindings.json but don't want to do it every time I make a change.  I have not found a 3rd party extension that works.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I too would like to be able to sync my keyboard shortcuts across platforms. I use both macOS and Windows

Comment: Don't worry, it doesn't work that great in Windows-to-windows either. Most often I need to copy keybindings.json manually across my windows machines too.

Answer (score 1):

There are "Keybindings Per Platform" setting in VS Code which can be disabled to propagate keybindings across different platforms.

But you must know that some of the bindings might not work due to different interpretation of some keys on different platforms.

I personally find it more convinient to set up my keybindings one more time on the new operating system.